# ¿Como modificar un objeto recién creado del dom con una función?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema. Tengo que crear múltiples tablas y lo quiero hacer desde JS en función de unos datos de entrada. Además quiero definir ciertas propiedades (como la fuente de la letra, la alineación y el "colspan") de forma variable con una función (para evitar escribir el código multiples veces), del siguiente estilo:

```js
var etd = document.createElement("td");

propiedades(etd, 5, 5, "left");

function propiedades(elemento,tamaFuente,tamaColumna,alineacion)
{
    elemento.style.textAlign = alineacion;
    elemento.colSpan = tamaColumna;
    elemento.style.fontSize = tamaFuente;
}//end function propiedades
```

es posible esto?

Comment: ¿Lo has probado? Creo que podrías responderte fácilmente

Comment: Para crear una tabla de manera dinámica necesitas primero establecer cuantos elementos `<td>` quieres poner en cada `<tr>`. Después necesitas crear los elementos `<tr>` para albergar los `<td>`.  Al final tendrás que crear algunos elementos `<td>` vacíos si no tienes bastantes elementos `<td>` para completar la fila. En lo que concierne los estilos que quieres añadir dinámicamente probablemente será más fácil hacerlo en el CSS utilizando selectores como `nth-of-type` Sería interesante ver primero un ejemplo de tabla para saber como crearlo dinámicamente.